# AngularJS Array Not Loading On View Load, but Alerts/Console Work

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to push values into an array as follows, but it is showing as an empty array. Alerting works. I am sure I am missing something obvious. Any clues? I have included the code with the just the array push attempt and another entry of code that has working alerts.

```
    $scope.termsArray = [];

    execOperation();

    function execOperation() {
        //Current Context
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //Current Taxonomy Session
        var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
        //Term Stores
        var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
        //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
        var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_111111111111");
        //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
        var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("12345-55-689");
        var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
        context.load(terms);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
            while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
                $scope.termsArray.push({
                                termName: currentTerm.get_name(),
                                termGUID: currentTerm.get_id(),
                                termSynonyms: 'Coming Soon'
                            });
            }

        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
    }
```

Here is the code with working alerts:

```
function execOperation() {
        //Current Context
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //Current Taxonomy Session
        var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
        //Term Stores
        var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
        //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
        var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_111111111111");
        //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
        var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("12345-55-689");
        var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
        context.load(terms);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
            var termList = "Terms: \n";
            while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
                $scope.termsArray.push({
                    termName: currentTerm.get_name(),
                    termGUID: currentTerm.get_id(),
                    termSynonyms: 'Coming Soon'
                });

                termList += currentTerm.get_id() + currentTerm.get_name() + "\n";
            }
            alert(termList);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
    }
```

Here is the HTML output:

```
<div> {{termsArray}}</div>
```

It returns []

**Update:** If I click in an input box and back out, or click an alert and hit ok, it then loads the array instead of loading on page load.

Comment: Where do you try to display it ? Where have you placed your working alert ?

Comment: where is ```termName: currentTerm. termGUID: currentTerm. termSynonyms: 'Coming Soon'``` coming from ? you are missing some code here. At the end put a ```console.log($scope.termsArray)``` and let us see what returns. And also, put this ```execOperation();``` at the end of the function.

Comment: Looks like an async issue. where do you show the content and how

Comment: Are you sure that currentTerm.get_name() and currentTerm.get_id() return a value ?

Comment: They are returning values. (ex. var termList = "Terms: \n"; termList += currentTerm.get_id() + currentTerm.get_name() + "\n"; alert(termList);

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer, I tried the end of the function, but not such changes. It logs as empty, but the alerts are working. I have updated my post with both attempts

Comment: Put the html/DOM where you are trying to see that code. If the console.log is giving you something, maybe you are not rendering the values very well.

Comment: It has been added to the original post. Very simple $scope call

Comment: Weird, the array populates if I click into the page. Ex. click into and out of a input such as: <input class="form-control" name="title" id="title" type="text" data-ng-model="itemtitle" placeholder="Add your title (Limited to 70 characters)" data-ng-maxlength="70" required>

Comment: The array also appears once an alert fires and I select ok. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track the issue down. It appears that Angular doesn't respect non-Angular functions on load, so I needed to wrap the $scoped array in a $scope.apply. Please see here for details: [Execute SharePoint Function On Page Load in AngularJS Application ($scope issue???)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349856/execute-sharepoint-function-on-page-load-in-angularjs-application-scope-issue/30375794#30375794)